# How to run threads in parallel in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio

I'm trying to run multiple threads in parallel. I tried to achieve this by having multiple instances of a thread. My assumption is that it will be executed simultaneously; however, the threads are being executed in a sequence.

Here's a simple code I tested:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
                LMLog.info("THREAD", "Counting " + i + " in Thread A");
            }
        }
    }).start();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
                LMLog.info("THREAD", "Counting " + i + " in Thread B");
            }
        }
    }).start();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
                LMLog.info("THREAD", "Counting " + i + " in Thread C");
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

And the log shows that the for loops are being executed one after another

Counting from 0 to 99 in Thread `A`, followed by the same thing in Thread `B` and Thread `C`.

Based on this, I concluded that they were not being executed in parallel as I thought they would be, but rather in a sequence.

How can I achieve parallel execution in Android then?

Comment: What does `100` equate to in CPU time? I doubt any valuable data can be obtained by that.

Comment: inside each loop add `Thread.sleep(100)` and rerun your code

Answer (score 10):

I might be wrong, but I think your conclusion is faulty. The reason for it is that counting to 100 takes such a short time that it probably takes more time to instantiate a new Thread and start it. If you want to ensure that your test is "valid" you should first instantiate all 3 threads and then start them all, something like this (also increase counter to 10k or 100k):

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
            LMLog.info("THREAD", "Counting " + i + " in Thread A");
        }
    }
Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
            LMLog.info("THREAD", "Counting " + i + " in Thread B");
        }
    }
Thread t3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
            LMLog.info("THREAD", "Counting " + i + " in Thread C");
        }
    }
t1.start(); t2.start(); t3.start();
```

This is purely for making your 'test' work. You can also use **AsyncTask** or some other methods.

Answer (score 3):

Its better to use `AsyncTask` and you can use `Thread_POOL_EXECUTOR` to run multiple tasks in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Executors](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class they provide a variety of thread pools.

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numOfYourThreads)
```

But beware not to start too many threads and stress your CPU too much.

Edit:
As I see the canon seems to be AsyncTask which only applies to short operations. If you have to use a longer Task either use a [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) or a ExecutorService.

Comment: How to use intent services if I have to execute an indefinite task?

Answer (score 1):

This is how to use `ExecutorService`

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
  executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // do something
        }
    });

executorService.shutdown();
```